# How can I search for someones name then replace the number in that same line as the persons name?

Tags: python, replace, find

I have the following data in a file called `data.txt` and would like to be able to add to the numbers at the end and replace them in the file without creating a new one:

```
Alfreda,art,2015,35
brook,biology,2015,3
charlie,chemistry,2015,140
dolly,Design,2015,120
Emilia,English,2015,150
Fiona,french,2015,40
Grace,Greek,2015,12
Hanna,history,2015,15
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
  newline=[]
  for word in f.line(): 
      newline.append(word.replace(35,str(New))
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
  for line in newline :
      f.writelines(line)
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your expected output. And please explain how the program knows what line to change.

Comment: for example: i would want to be able to search for the name and if the line starts with the name, i would want to be able to update the numbers : Alfreda,art,2015,40
brook,biology,2015,5
charlie,chemistry,2015,150
dolly,Design,2015,120
Emilia,English,2015,150
Fiona,french,2015,40
Grace,Greek,2015,14
Hanna,history,2015,10

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still not clear. You say "add the numbers at the end". If you add 25 to `Alfreda,art,2015,35` do you want the result to be `Alfreda,art,2015,35,25` or  `Alfreda,art,2015,60`?

Comment: Alfreda,art,2015,60

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add string to each line then update the file, this code can solve your problem but this is not optimal.

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as myFile:
  newline=[]
  # Use the readlines method to get all the lines
  for line in myFile.readlines():
      # Remove the \n character with the rstrip method
      line = line.rstrip('\n')
      newline.append(line+",35\n") # Don't forget to add \n
# Test
print newline
myFile.close()
with open("data.txt", "w") as myFile:
  for line in newline :
      myFile.writelines(line)
```

If this is not your problem, try to use the pickle module and work with objects, it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to make some of your question up. If you have a file and you want to update it, the updates *have to come from somewhere*. The code in the question has a `New` variable but there is no indication of how `New` is supposed to get a value, or how the program is supposed to know which row to update.

I'm going to assume you have a *file* of updates called `updates.txt` that looks like this (and it is deliberately not in alphabetical order):

```
Emilia,45
Alfreda,35
```

So after your program runs the resulting file will have two rows different:

```
Alfreda,art,2015,70                                  ...this one
brook,biology,2015,3
charlie,chemistry,2015,140
dolly,Design,2015,120
Emilia,English,2015,195                              ...and this one
Fiona,french,2015,40
Grace,Greek,2015,12
Hanna,history,2015,15
```

But the rest the same.

Since your sample data file is a `.csv` file I am using the Python `csv` module, rather than picking the data apart by hand. It doesn't matter much with simple data like this but it's a good module to know about.

```
import csv
marks = {}

# Read in existing data into a dictionary:
# key is name, value is a list [subject, year, score]
# like this: {"Alfreda": ["art",2015,35], ... }  
# This is to make it easy to do random updates based on name

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        name,subject,year,score = row
        marks[name] = [subject,int(year),int(score)]

# Read in updates and apply each line to the corresponding entry in marks
with open("updates.txt", "r") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        name,added_score = row
        try:
            marks[name][2] += int(added_score)  # for example marks["Alfreda"][2] += int("35")
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Name {name} not found to update, nothing done")

# Write out updated dictionary:
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,lineterminator="\n")
    for name in sorted(marks.keys(), key=lambda n: n.lower()):
        row=[name]+marks[name]                 # for example ["Alfreda"] + ["art",2015,70]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This line:

```
for name in sorted(marks.keys(), key=lambda n: n.lower()):
```

looks complicated but it is needed because you obviously expect the names `Alfreda brook charlie dolly Emilia Fiona Grace Hanna` to be in that order. But just doing the obvious

```
for name in sorted(marks.keys()):
```

will put them in the order `Alfreda Emilia Fiona Grace Hanna brook charlie dolly`.

In the interests of keeping the code simple and as close to your original as possible, it does no validity checks, so if this line

```
charlie,chemistry,2015,140
```

was wrongly entered as

```
charlie,chemistry,2015,14O
```

(with the letter O instead of a zero), the program will just fail. Ditto if the update file is missing a comma somewhere.

This works and will do what I think you want. But...

There are issues with the design. Your program reads in the data from `data.txt`, then overwrites it with new data. But suppose your program fails just after this line:

```
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
```

Then you won't have your original data (because the call to `open()` truncated it), and you won't have the new data either (because you haven't written it out yet). Or suppose you accidentally run the program twice. There will be no way to tell you have done that.

You can provide some insurance against this sort of mishap by using the `fileinput` module, like this:

```
import fileinput

# Read in existing data
with fileinput.input("data.txt", inplace=True, backup=".bkp") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        name,subject,year,score = row
        marks[name] = [subject,int(year),int(score)]
```

With this change, your updates will be in `data.txt` as before, but your original data will still be around, in a file called `data.txt.bkp`.

But that is just a fix. It avoids the real issue, which is that you really have a database application and you are trying to implement it using textfiles. The code above is all very well for an exercise, but it's not robust and it won't scale.

Comment: there is an error                                                                                                    with open("updates.txt", "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'updates.txt'

Comment: Did you create the file? It's up to you to provide it.